# Getting error as "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): that.setState is not a function" in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, dynamic-chart-series

I am currently working on a dynamic chart which change based on Slider value. I searched for a solution, and everyone says I need to bind it to get this error go away. However I have tried to bind the function in all possible ways still I get this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): that.setState is not a function.

Relevant code:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      slideValue: 200,
      slidebgColor: "47CF8E",
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [0],
        datasets: [{
          label: '',
          data: [0, 1],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
          ]
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              autoskip: true
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            display: false
          }]
        }
      }
    }
    this.handleSliderEvent = this.handleSliderEvent.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("inside componentDidMount");
  }

  getChartData = e => {
    const data1 = this.state.data;
    const slideValue = this.state.slideValue;
    const backColor = ["pink", "purple", "blue", "green", "lightblue", "neon", "red", "lightgreen", "yellow", "grey", "lightgrey", "orange"]

    for (let i = 0; i < slideValue; i++) {
      const randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * slideValue);

      data1.labels[i] = randomNumber;
      data1.datasets[0].data[i] = randomNumber;
      data1.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] = "purple";
    }

    this.setState = {
      data: data1
    }

    return data1;
  }

  handleSliderEvent = async (event) => {
    let slideValue1 = event;
    let that = this;

    that.setState({
      slideValue: slideValue1
    })
  };

  render() {
    const type = this.state.type;
    const options = this.state.options;
    const data = this.state.data;
    const slideValue = this.state.slideValue;
    const value = this.state.value;

    return (
      <div style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
        <div style={{ height: 400, display: "inline-flex", paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
          <Slider
            defaultValue={200}
            vertical
            progress
            min={0}
            max={this.state.slideValue}
            onChange={this.handleSliderEvent}
          />
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: "inline-flex", position: "relative", width: 600, height: 550, paddingLeft: "10%" }}>
          <Bar
            type={type}
            options={options}
            data={this.getChartData}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Can anyone please suggests what went wrong?

Comment: It's an arrow function, so binding `this` in the constructor isn't necessary. Just as unnecessary as `let that = this`. Also is there a reason the function is async?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:

```
that.setState(...);
```

Rather than:

```
this.setState(...);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
handleSliderEvent = async (event) => {
    let slideValue1 = event;
    // let that=this;

    console.log("slideValue :", slideValue1)

    //that.setState ({
    this.setState({
        slideValue: slideValue1
    });

    console.log(this.state.slideValue);
};
```

Comment: I tried this.setState(...) previously, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks Russell, but it still isn't working. I tried again just now. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Previously you've tried `this.setState = {};`. What if you try that again, i.e. `this.setState = {slideValue: slideValue1};`

Comment: @BrianThompson, the error given is "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): that.setState is not a function", and in the code example `this.setState` has been assigned to

Comment: @ReeceRussell I don't think you're understanding the error in the context of a React Class Component. `this.setState` is a function defined by the super class `React.Component`. It should not be re-assigned.

Comment: @BrianThompson I'm aware of the React Component, I was just throwing an idea out there. The reassigning of the setState function is most likely another, unrelated issue with the author's example.

Comment: Why would it be unrelated? If you wrote `let func = () => {}; func = 'something'; func();` What would you expect to happen? It would throw this same error in question. This is the root problem. You can't reassign a function to some other datatype and then expect to be able to call it.

Comment: @BrianThompson I've reviewed your answer, and I agree. I admit defeat in where I wasn't looking closely enough :D

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use `let that = this`?

Isn't it better to do something like:

```
 handleSliderEvent = async (event) => {
    
        this.setState({
            slideValue: event
        })
      };
```

Besides that I believe your TypeError come from other place:

```
getChartData=e=>{
...

this.setState = { data: data1 }
```

Instead of using:

```
 this.setState({ data: data1 })
```

Comment: yeah "let that= this" is redundant, i didn't use it initially. but since my solution wasn't working so i tried to store "this" into "that" just for a change (read it somewhere online).

Comment: I believe your error come from getChartData, because you using setState like this:
    this.setState = {
        data: data1
    }

instead of this.setState({data: data1});

Comment: Hi Mounique, i changed getChartData, now i am getting new error which says as below: "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." any thoughts?

Comment: @AnkitL This is a new error and a new problem. You should open a new question for it if you cant figure it out. Then you can provide the appropriate context for the question, such as a formatted error message, the code, the library names or component code for `Slider` and `Bar`, etc. The question here and the new error message are not related so it will be confusing for future readers.

Comment: Try to call you getChartData like this   data = {() => this.getChartData()}

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks for the support. I will ask a new question if i couldn't fix this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this bit of code inside `getChartData`:

```js
this.setState = {
  data: data1
}
```

You're reassigning the `setState` function instead of calling it with updated data. This means the next time you attempt to call `this.setState` it will break, because now it is an object instead of a function. Simply change it to this:

```js
this.setState({
  data: data1
})
```

Also, as stated in the comments: `let that = this` is useless as well as the binding in the contructor. An arrow function does not need that workaround.

Comment: Hi Brian, I changed it to this:
this.setState = ({
            data: data1
        }).  but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @AnkitL Nope, that's still an assignment. Remove the `=`. It needs to be a function call. You can copy it exactly as I put in the answer, that is what it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that error is gone but encountered a new error now.
"Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."  Any thoughts?

Comment: Cool. That error is unrelated to the cause of this one, so you're making progress! Something is triggering an infinite setState loop, but I can't see what would be causing it from the code in question..